# Why are the largest land/air animals today smaller than in the Mesozoic?

Tags: palaeontology

[The largest dinosaurs and pterosaurs seem to have been much larger than the largest animal terrestrial/avian species since](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_prehistoric_animals). Was the Mesozoic somehow more hospitable to large animal species than today's world? Have subsequent evolutionary innovations shifted the balance towards smaller species?

Interestingly [the still-existing blue whale seems to be the largest animal ever](http://animals.howstuffworks.com/animal-facts/question687.htm).

Comment: Closely related/maybe partial duplicate of [*What are the atmospheric requirements for large dinosaurs?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20656/what-are-the-atmospheric-requirements-for-large-dinosaurs) and [*What was the reason for some plant and animals to become giant in course of evolution?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/what-was-the-reason-for-some-plant-and-animals-to-become-giant-in-course-of-evol/1778#1778)

Comment: Although the specified question is not an exact duplicate, [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/1825/4697) pretty much covers my question.